# count of duplicate xml nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i am using xmllint (xslt 1.0) to query documents for nodes having count > 1.  based on the below, i want to get the make nodes where the value occurs more than one time (Ford and Chevy). Seeing the count would be ideal too :)

```
<cars>
  <car>
    <make>Ford</make><model>Tempo</model>
  </car>
  <car>
    <make>Ford</make><model>Mustang</model>
  </car>
  <car>
    <make>Chevy</make><model>Malibu</model>
  </car>
  <car>
    <make>Chevy</make><model>Camaro</model>
  </car>
  <car>
    <make>Honda</make><model>CRV</model>
  </car>
</cars>
```

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Come back if you have a **specific** question regarding the implementation.

Comment: What is your XPath version?

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 and later.

```
for $node in distinct-values(/cars/car/make) 
return if (count(/cars/car[make = $node]) > 1) then concat($node," : ", count(/cars/car[make = $node]))
else ()
```